# how to add selected checkboxes in Textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/12/),There is a `to` button.

When the `to` button is pressed a pop up appears with a drop down menu.

From the drop down menu a user either selects `users` or `groups` then a table with check boxed rows appear.

Now, after selecting a few check boxes and hitting the `ok` button, the selected check boxes name should be displayed in the `textfield`.

I am doing this like this:

```
 $('#mytable tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i)
    {               
       sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
         //alert("hello " +sCheckbox);
```

But its not working.

I added an `alert`, but still,  the alert is not showing which means the control is not going inside.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Replace `sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));` with `sCheckbox.push($(this).html());`

Comment: @ManofSnow Thanks for replying,I did as you said http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/13/ but still the same.Can you please tell me why the control is not going inside.Why `alert("hello " +sCheckbox);` is not showing?

Comment: the alert is popping up for me, and the values are populated... nothing is `null` so something is showing. The output in the alert I am getitng is from this section of code: `var ds = (sCheckbox.length > 0) ? sCheckbox.join(",") : ""; alert("ds is "+ds); });`

Comment: You're reading from the wrong table. Your selector specifies `#groupsTable` (for instance), but the groups table in the modal has no id on it. Your selector is reading the checkboxes from the main page instead.

Comment: @Phlume this alert is poping `alert("ds is "+ds);` but this not `alert("hello " +sCheckbox);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading from the wrong table. Your selector specifies #groupsTable (for instance), but the groups table in the modal has no id on it. Your selector is reading the checkboxes from the main page instead.

You can either add ids to your tables in the modal div, or use these selectors instead:

```
$('#ToOk').click(function(){
 $('#users tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {               
                    sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
                    //alert("hello " +sCheckbox);
            });
    $('#groups  tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i) {               
                    sCheckbox.push($(this).attr("data-id"));
                    //alert("hello " +sCheckbox);
            });
    var ds = (sCheckbox.length > 0) ? sCheckbox.join(",") : "";
alert("ds is "+ds);
});
```

Comment: well can you please tell me how to get the names and add into the textfield,I am new to jquery So asking foolish questions

Comment: The easiest way would be to put a class on the column you want to pull ('username', maybe), and then something like `$('#groups  tr input[type="checkbox"]:checked').parent().next('.username')`

Comment: This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LBPB6/16/ I created after your answer.Can you please update this

Comment: Which this? No link in that comment.

Comment: hey sorry forgot to add.Now see

Comment: I waiting for the answer

Comment: In your comment, it sounds like you want the usernames in the text field (though other things indicate a number). Have updated the fiddle to demonstrate putting the names there; you should be able to use the same approach to get the numbers instead if that's what you need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44923/discussion-between-jquerylearner-and-s-mccrohan)

Comment: any solutions you have?